# How to set font size of 'open file tabs'?

Tags: sublimetext2

I added `"font.size": 15.0` to the `tab_label` class in `Default.sublime-theme`.

```
{
    "class": "tab_label",
    "fg": [0, 0, 0, 255],
    "shadow_color": [255, 255, 255, 80],
    "shadow_offset": [0, 1],
    "font.size": 15.0
}
```

The font size did change, but the lower parts of the file names somehow 'get cut'.

[image]

What should I do?